# Freemarker: Loading templates from different locations

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to load templates for Freemarker from 2 different places.  The folders where the ftl files are located are:

```
/docroot/WEB-INF/src/charts/base
/docroot/WEB-INF/src/charts/tmpl
```

I have the following class with 2 methods:

```
public class TemplateLoader {

    public Template loadChartBaseTemplate(String templateName) throws Exception {

        String templateFile = String.format("%s.ftl", templateName);

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/charts/base/");
        Template template = cfg.getTemplate(templateFile);

        return template;

    }

    public Template loadChartTemplate(String fileName) throws Exception {

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/charts/tmpl/");
        Template template = cfg.getTemplate(fileName);

        return template;

    }

}
```

The first method loads the templates properly.  The second method returns an error saying "Template not found for name ".  Both folders are at the same level and I checked that the files I am trying to load exist.

What may cause Freemarker to be able to load the templates from one folder and fail for the other, given that they are at the same level (I tried with the ending "/" and without it and it makes no difference, the behavior is the same).

One additional question:

The following lines return the error: The constructor Configuration() is deprecated

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
```

All documentation and examples I have seen have it like this.  Is there other way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the two directories coming from different jar-s? The reason FreeMarker requires a class as the first parameter is that it will use the defining `ClassLoader` of that class to load the templates. In some setups (particularly under OSGi), you have to be careful to chose a class that comes from the same jar that contains the templates. If it still doesn't work, just to rule out FreeMarker as a possible cause, you could try if you can load the desired template via `Class.getResourceAsStream(...)`.

Deprecation: Deprecation is not an error. As the deprecation message says: "Use Configuration(Version) instead." This is also how it is in the FreeMarker documentation, which should be used as the primary source for FreeMarker related information.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I just figured out what is happening here.  I am working with a Liferay portlet.  The template in "base" is added in the project.  The "tmpl" folder is empty and the ftl file that goes there is created during runtime.  What happens is that, the debugger is looking for the files in the source code folder (Eclipse Workspace), where "tmpl" folder is empty; the file I am creating in runtime is being created in the deployed folder (Liferay's Apache webapps folder).  In summary, the debugger is looking for the ftl file in an incorrect location.